# Symfony2 / Typecasting query results to simpeler object

Tags: symfony, tree, doctrine-orm

I am using Stof's DoctrineExtension bundle to retrieve my Tree, now I want to convert that tree to an array (which will then in turn get converted to json).

The format of NestedTreeRepository->childrenHierarchy() is not in the correct format though, I want to modify the output so only the node "title" property and the "id" property is returned, and put any children in a "children" subarray. In compliance with this format (JSON):

```
{
        label: 'node1',
        children: [
            { label: 'child1' },
            { label: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to following code, this returns the same as childrenHierarchy() but would allow me to modify the query.

```
    $query = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('node')
            ->from('MyBundle:Page', 'node')
            ->orderBy('node.root, node.lft', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
    ;
    $nodes = $query->getArrayResult();

    [Do magic here]

    $tree = $pagerepo->buildTree($nodes);
```

Is it possible to typecast every node into a much simpler object containing only the following property's:

- id
- title
- a few other ints used for positioning

if I would then run that through json_encode() I would have exactly what I needed.

Any other solutions are of course welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code for this purpose (just made this a few hours ago)
it's a remake of stof's buildTreeArray function

in the controller (I'm writing this for symfony2):

```
function gettreeAction {
    $query = .... // do your query
    $tree = $this->buildTree($query->getArrayResult());
    $response = new Response(json_encode($tree));
    return $response;
}

private function buildTree($nodes) 
{
    $nestedTree = array();
    $l = 0;

    if (count($nodes) > 0) {
        // Node Stack. Used to help building the hierarchy
        $stack = array();
        foreach ($nodes as $child) {
            $item = array();
            $item['name'] = $child['title'];
            $item['id'] = 'page_'.$child['id'];
            $item['level'] = $child['level'];
            $item['children'] = array();
            // Number of stack items
            $l = count($stack);
            // Check if we're dealing with different levels
            while($l > 0 && $stack[$l - 1]['level'] >= $item['level']) {
                array_pop($stack);
                $l--;
            }
            // Stack is empty (we are inspecting the root)
            if ($l == 0) {
                // Assigning the root child
                $i = count($nestedTree);
                $nestedTree[$i] = $item;
                $stack[] = &$nestedTree[$i];
            } else {
                // Add child to parent
                $i = count($stack[$l - 1]['children']);
                $stack[$l - 1]['children'][$i] = $item;
                $stack[] = &$stack[$l - 1]['children'][$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return $nestedTree;
}
```

works perfectly with jqTree...

Comment: I am trying to implement this extending a class in the StofDoctrineExtensionBundle which would be more tidy in my opinion. If you are interested, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161371/overriding-doctrineextensions-method-in-stofdoctrineextensions

Comment: A commit was made to Gedmo's doctrine-extensions so you can choose what the key of the children subarray is:

$repo->setChildrenIndex('myChildren');

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Stofs Repository function](http://www.gediminasm.org/article/tree-nestedset-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2) to get the nodes in an hierarchical array:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Page');
$arrayTree = $repo->childrenHierarchy();
```

And I think there is no other solution than modify that array manually. After you have removed some properties that you dont need, you can json_encode the array and return it.

Comment: Well, this
    $nodes = $query->getArrayResult();
gives me a flat array, I could then loop through it using a foreach, and instantiate new, simpler, objects. 

I think typecasting isn't even possible, as I would then have to make Page a subtype of this simpler object. Which doctrine might not like. Will report back

Comment: in fact ->getArrayResult() doesn't return Page objects, but an array containing more Array's representing the Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it as following:

```
public function getPageTreeAction() {

    $pagerepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Page');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('node')
            ->from('MyCorpBundle:Page', 'node')
            ->orderBy('node.root, node.lft', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();

    $flatnodearray = $query->getArrayResult();
    $flatsimplenodearray = array();

    foreach ($flatnodearray as $currentNode) {
        $currentSimpleNode = array();

        $currentSimpleNode['id'] = $currentNode['id'];
        $currentSimpleNode['lft'] =$currentNode['lft'];
        $currentSimpleNode['rgt'] = $currentNode['rgt'];
        $currentSimpleNode['lvl'] = $currentNode['lvl'];
        $currentSimpleNode['title'] = $currentNode['title'];

        $flatsimplenodearray[] = $currentSimpleNode;
    }

    $tree = $pagerepo->buildTree($flatsimplenodearray);
    $response = new Response(json_encode($tree));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```