# Overriding DoctrineExtensions method in StofDoctrineExtensions

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony

I am trying to change the behaviour of the Gedmo\Tree\RepositoryUtils->buildTree() method because I'd like to change the way the returned array is constructed.

I am trying to following:

I have a class:

```
<?php

namespace MyCorp\CMSBundle\Util;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;

/**
 * Description of jsandjqTreeCompatibleRepositoryUtils
 *
 * @author peterrus
 */
class jsandjqTreeCompatibleRepositoryUtils extends Gedmo\Tree\RepositoryUtils {

    public function buildTree(array $nodes, array $options = array()) {

        $meta = $this->getClassMetadata();
        $nestedTree = $this->repo->buildTreeArray($nodes);

        $default = array(
            'decorate' => false,
            'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
            'rootClose' => '</ul>',
            'childOpen' => '<li>',
            'childClose' => '</li>',
            'nodeDecorator' => function ($node) use ($meta) {
                // override and change it, guessing which field to use
                if ($meta->hasField('title')) {
                    $field = 'title';
                } elseif ($meta->hasField('name')) {
                    $field = 'name';
                } else {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot find any representation field");
                }
                return $node[$field];
            }
        );
        $options = array_merge($default, $options);
        // If you don't want any html output it will return the nested array
        if (!$options['decorate']) {
            return $nestedTree;
        }

        if (!count($nestedTree)) {
            return '';
        }

        $build = function($tree) use (&$build, &$options) {
                    $output = is_string($options['rootOpen']) ? $options['rootOpen'] : $options['rootOpen']($tree);
                    foreach ($tree as $node) {
                        $output .= is_string($options['childOpen']) ? $options['childOpen'] : $options['childOpen']($node);
                        $output .= $options['nodeDecorator']($node);
                        if (count($node['children']) > 0) {
                            $output .= $build($node['children']);
                        }
                        $output .= $options['childClose'];
                    }
                    return $output . $options['rootClose'];
                };

        return $build($nestedTree);
    }

}

?>
```

Now I am trying to use this class instead of the one that is used by default when calling

```
$pagerepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyCorpCMSBundle:Page');
```

By doing the following typecasting:

```
$pagerepo = (jsandjqTreeCompatibleRepositoryUtils) $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyCorpCMSBundle:Page');
```

But as this is no java, this is not possible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is also discussed here https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/issues/442

Comment: I am instantiating as follows:

Code:


`$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $pagerepo = $em->getRepository('MyCorpCMSBundle:Page');
        $pagerepo->setRepoUtils(new jsandjqTreeCompatibleRepositoryUtils());`

this is getting in the right direction, however the RepositoryUtils object needs some parameters

`public function __construct(ObjectManager $om, ClassMetadata $meta, $listener, $repo)`

where do I retrieve these from?

Answer (score 0):

May be a little late, but i needed to to the same thing - here is the solution in case someone else needs it:

Your Repository Class:

```
namespace Acme\Model\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use MyNamespace\GenericBundle\Repository\RepositoryUtils as MyRepositoryUtils;

/**
 * Group Repository
 */
class CategoryRepository extends NestedTreeRepository
{
    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param ClassMetadata $class
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, $class);
        $this->repoUtils = new MyRepositoryUtils($this->_em, $this->getClassMetadata(), $this->listener, $this);
    }
}
```

in the MyRepositoryUtils you can overwrite the buildTree method:

```
namespace MyNamespace\GenericBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Gedmo\Tree\RepositoryUtils as GedmoRepositoryUtils;

class RepositoryUtils extends GedmoRepositoryUtils
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildTree(array $nodes, array $options = array())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/rufinus/99f6808d0b4fe2b51530 for an example on how to get this working with jquery Nestable plugin